# This word could not be fit on page. It will not be plotted. (Wordcloud)

Tags: r, text-mining, word-frequency

I am trying to print a wordcloud with 10 terms.
My data is:

```
freq.df$word <- c("toque queda","recorrido habitual","prevencion quedateencasa","mensaje directo","medidas preventivas","medidas prevencion","juntoslogramosmas prevencion","desvio linea","coronavirus 

covid19","colectivos desvio")

freq.df$freq <- c(2320,2780,3020,2560,3390,3970,5180,2660,4580,3020)
```

The code I use is:

```
pal=brewer.pal(8,"PuBu")

wordcloud(freq.df$word,freq.df$freq,random.order = F, colors=pal)
```

But it returns the following error of several words:

```
 Warning in wordcloud(freq.df$word, freq.df$freq, random.order = F, colors = pal) :
  juntoslogramosmas prevencion could not be fit on page. It will not be plotted.
Warning in wordcloud(freq.df$word, freq.df$freq, random.order = F, colors = pal) :
  coronavirus covid19 could not be fit on page. It will not be plotted.
Warning in wordcloud(freq.df$word, freq.df$freq, random.order = F, colors = pal) :
  medidas prevencion could not be fit on page. It will not be plotted.
Warning in wordcloud(freq.df$word, freq.df$freq, random.order = F, colors = pal) :
  medidas preventivas could not be fit on page. It will not be plotted.
Warning in wordcloud(freq.df$word, freq.df$freq, random.order = F, colors = pal) :
  prevencion quedateencasa could not be fit on page. It will not be plotted.
```

How can I solve that? Thanks!

Comment: Try adjusting the scale option `scale=c(4, .5)` in the wordcloud function, using a max size smaller than 4 may allow the words to fit on the page.

Comment: Great it has served me with a scale of 2. Thank you very much